# Returning Future from try-resource structure

Tags: java, return, try-catch, future, autocloseable

I have the following method which uses Apache Commons Http client sending asynchronous GET to the given URI and returning Future with the response.

CloseableHttpAsyncClient implements Closeable thus I use try/resource constructure.

```
public static Future<HttpResponse> sendAsyncGet(String uri) throws IOException {
    try (CloseableHttpAsyncClient asyncHttpClient = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault()) {
        asyncHttpClient.start();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
        return asyncHttpClient.execute(httpGet, null);
    }
```

Below you may see the usage:

```
Future<HttpResponse> future = sendAsyncGet("http://www.apache.org");
future.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The problem is that when I call get on a future it doesn't return the desired HttpResponse. It waits until timeout exceeded or forever if I use the overloaded get() method. I guess this is because try/resource wasn't released properly.

How can I improve the given method/code to be able to properly use: Future with try/resource structure included in method body?

**Update:**

This is maven dependency:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: “The problem is that when I call get on a future it doesn't return the desired HttpResponse. It waits until timeout exceeded or forever if I use the overloaded get() method.”  Yes, that's how Future is supposed to work.  If you don't want it to wait, why did you tell it to wait three seconds?

Comment: Leaving the try/resource-block will call close() on the opened asyncHttpClient. I assume that the closed httpClient does not call complete or completeExceptionally on the future you are waiting for. Consult the documentation of the used library!

Comment: @VGR: When I modify the method (e.g. I change it's signature to void) and handle the futureResponse in the try/resource statement I'm able to run the get() on a future and get the result.
The problem is I don't know how can I return 'future' from this method and make sure the resource will be closed after I call get() on that future outside the method.
Is that possible? I guess not and If not then how can I solve the problem in the other way? I just want to pass URI to the method and force method to do all the dirty job for me and close the connection after it finish it.

Comment: @Heri: You might be right. I debugged the code and close() is called before I call get() on a future. I will investigate http client, but I'm curious is there any other way to work around that?

Answer (score 1):

Try with resources will close the async client before the response has been received.

You might want to close the async client from a future callback you had passed to the execute call.

```
public static Future<HttpResponse> sendAsyncGet(String uri) throws IOException {
    final CloseableHttpAsyncClient asyncHttpClient;

    asyncHttpClient = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
    asyncHttpClient.start();

    return asyncHttpClient.execute(new HttpGet(uri), new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {
        private void close() {
            try {
                asyncHttpClient.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void completed(HttpResponse response) {
            close();
            System.out.println("completed");
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Exception e) {
            close();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelled() {
            close();
            System.out.println("cancelled");
        }
    });
}
```